# Extra horizontal space using \smash{\bm{...}} followed by subscript

Tags: spacing, boldmath

I am trying to typeset `\smash{\bm{U}}_\rho`; however, the spacing is different from `\bm{U}_\rho`. I have tried `\!` to restore the spacing, but that's too tight. How can I restore the original spacing despite using `\smash`?

See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\smash{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\matfix}[1]{\smash{\bm{#1}}\!}
\begin{document}
    $\bm{U}_\rho$

    $\mat{U}_\rho$

    $\matfix{U}_\rho$
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `\smash`?

Comment: @egreg mostly making sure that `\mat{\tilde{U}}` does not appear higher than `\mat{U}`, such that `\left( \mat{\tilde{U}} \right)` results in same-size parentheses as `\left( \mat{U} \right)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of `\smash` is (I believe you'll get into troubles).

Here's a solution anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mat}{m e{_^}}{%
  \smash{\bm{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\tuckin{#1}{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}%
}

\newcommand{\tuckin}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\tuckinauxA{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\tuckinauxA}[2]{\tuckinauxB#1#2}
\newcommand{\tuckinauxB}[3]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\bm{#2}_{#3}$}%
  \sbox2{$#1{{}\bm{#2}}_{#3}$}%
  \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax
  _{\kern\dimen0 #3}%
}

\begin{document}

$\bm{U}_\rho$ \sbox0{$\bm{U}_\rho$}\the\wd0\ \the\ht0

$\mat{U}_\rho$ \sbox0{$\mat{U}_\rho$}\the\wd0\ \the\ht0

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, thanks! Regarding the trouble of `\smash`: is there a better way to make `\tilde{U}` the same size (well, just not higher would be enough) as `U`?

Comment: @bers Not sure what you mean: the height of `\tilde{U}` is obviously larger than the height of `U`.

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment to the original question, I am looking for ways to make `U` and `\tilde{U}` appear *to LaTeX* to have the same height, so that, for example, calculated heights of inter-line spacings and sizes of parentheses (`\left( ... \right)`) are the same for `U` and `\tilde{U}`. In other words, I would like `\left( ... \right)` (etc.) to ignore the effects of `\tilde`.

Comment: @bers Just don't use `\left` and `\right`, it's that easy. `;-)`

Comment: Maybe I will have to do just that ;)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is versatile but quite tricky. As mentioned in the comments, the aim is to ensure that `\mat{\tilde{U}}` has the same size as `\mat{U}`. It can be easily achieved using

```
\usepackage{mathtools}   % for \mathrlap
\newcommand{\tmat}[1]{\mathrlap{\smash{\bm{\tilde{#1}}}}\bm{#1}}
```

and replacing `\mat{\tilde{U}}_\rho` by `\tmat{U}_\rho`.
Note that the `U` symbol is printed twice and `\mathrlap{\smash{...}}` smashes the boundary box completely.